# AirPort Extreme only 1 client has an internet connection

Tags: network, airport, internet

A friend of mine has some trouble with his AirPort Extreme (Router). All of his clients (Macbook, iPad, iPhone, ...) do not connect to the internet, except one iMac in his office.

The AirPort Extreme is connected to a modem from his internet provider. If he connects a MacBook directly with the modem it has an internet connection.

I think all of the settings on the devices are the same as on the working iMac (IPv4 DHCP, IPv6 automatic).

Someone have an idea what I should check or a solution for this problem?

Comment: ok a Idea, does the network provider allow multiple simultaneous connections ? simple test, disconnect all then connect one by one.

Comment: I think yes, as the internet connection worked properly until yesterday. But I will check this tomorrow, maybe his ISP has made some changes.

Comment: You'll have to post some information on how things are set up; networking has many possible things that can go wrong, mostly down to various settings which don't match up.

Comment: What do you need for informations? I think most of the client settings are set to automatic mode such as DHCP for IPv4 and automatic for IPv6. Also the DNS server are the default ones. The same on router site. The clients get there IP via DHCP, the DNSs are the default ones (I also tried the Google DNS). IPv6 is on automatic and native mode. The Router is in bridge mode. I have also some screenshots, but there are in german language: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eieqjq44sq46st0/AAD48cYFng_e2GackVYHkwVxa?dl=0

Comment: Done a cold-boot on the network? Disconnect all devices, power off the modem and APExtreme. Boot the modem only; wait a few minutes then boot the APExtreme. Then check if your devices are able to connect with Internet access.

Comment: I found the solution. It was the modem that had very fault settings. (DHCP lease time below 10 seconds and DHCP-Pool-Size of 4). Corrected the settings and all working properly right now.